# multiple amcl on one odom

Tags: navigation, lidar, odometry, ros-kinetic, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to evaluate and compare 2 lidar performance at the same time on the same robot. I know amcl can only take in one odom at a time, is this possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345693/multiple-amcl-on-one-odom/) by [lunatic](https://answers.ros.org/users/52207/lunatic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess you misunderstood something. (Or I might be misunderstanding what you try to do).

Comparing the performance of 2 lidars by doing localization in a given map should be doable by running two `amcl` instances side by side. You only need to make sure to set `tf_broadcast` to false for at least one of the two nodes.

However, this then has nothing to do with `amcl` taking in multiple `odom`s (as you say). `amcl` retrieves the `odom`->`base_link` transform via `tf`. And then outputs the transform from  `map`->`odom` (if enabled).

You then need to compare the published `amcl_pose` and `particle_cloud` topics (make sure to remap those to unique names).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lunatic](https://answers.ros.org/users/52207/lunatic/) on 2020-03-18**:
Thank you. This works. However, I'm facing this issue to determine which lidar is better as I have no ground truth for these amcl_pose. The only ground truth that I can think of is to create a path for the robot and run pure pursuit but how do I compare them?